# integrating an angular plugin

Tags: angularjs, plugins

> I'm new to angular. I'm attempting to use this plugin:
>   http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-datepicker I've run bower and
>   grunt build, so I think I've got them installed correctly.
>
> When I launch the app with grunt serve, I get simply 'uncaught
>   object'.
>
> One of my handicaps is that I'm not entirely familiar with how the app
>   is set up.
>
> The dash.html page I'm working on has a dash-directive.js, like this:
>
> ```
> angular.module('sysomos.ads').
>   directive('sysReportViewQuery', [
>     function() {
>     }
>   ]).
>   //...etc.
>   directive('sysReportViewQueryToggle', [
>     function() {
>     }
>   ]);
> ```
>
> I thought perhaps I could add the dateRangePicker like this:
>
> ```
> angular.module('sysomos.ads',['dateRangePicker']).//etc
> ```
>
> but that doesn't work.
>
> There is also a very short file called app.js, to which I tried adding
>   the plugin as well: 'use strict';
>
> ```
> angular.module('sysomos.ads', [
>   'LocalStorageModule',
>   'ngCookies',
>     'ui.router',
>     'ngAnimate',
>     'mgcrea.ngStrap',
>     'sys.common.api',
>     'sys.common.auth',
>     'dateRangePicker'
> ]);
> ```
>
> but no joy.
>
> I realize I'm asking how my own app is built but I'm hoping this is a
>   common, recognizable setup.

**[UPDATE:]** 
In an attempt to get a proper foundation under this plugin installation, I have uninstalled it and deleted the files manually, then gone back and used bower to auto-install the datepicker from bower.io. It may or may not be the same module, it doesn't matter, I'm just trying to get SOMEthing installed.

When I grunt build, it gives me this message:

**angular-datepicker was not injected in your file.
Please go take a look in "app\public\lib\angular-datepicker" for the file you need, then manually include it in your file.**

What "file" am I manually including it in? and how? bower.json?

I'm guessing maybe this is a pathing issue - there are several subfolders inside angular-datepicker - I'd be surprised if it could find the right files:

```
-angular-datepicker
  -app
    -scripts
       -datePicker.js
       -dateRange.js
```

but I don't see how I'd fix it in the bower.json file - there's no paths there.

My root bower.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "sysomos-ads",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.16",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.10",
    "angular-strap": "2.0.2",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.16",
    "angular-motion": "0.3.2",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.16",
    "angular-local-storage": "0.0.5",
    "jquery": "1.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.1.1",
    "components-font-awesome": "4.1.0",
    "angular-datepicker": "~1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.16"
  }
}
```

And the angular-datepicker/bower.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "angular-datepicker",
  "license": "MIT",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "ignore": [
    ".gitignore","README.md"
  ],
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.0-rc.2",
    "jquery": "~2.0.2",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.0.5",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.0.5",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.3.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.0-rc.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dependencies looks good.

First of all after `bower install --save angular-datepicker` you have a directories:

```
-angular-datepicker
  -app
  -dist
  -test
```

so, you need to add only 2 files from **dist** directory :

```
index.js
index.css
```

this line:

```
angular.module('sysomos.ads',['dateRangePicker']).//etc
```

you must **change** to this:

```
angular.module('sysomos.ads',['datePicker']).//etc
```

And now you can use a datePicker like [here](https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
dateRangePicker
```

to

```
datePicker
```

And sure to add this script files

```
datePicker.js
dataRange.js
```

Comment: There are no datePicker.js or dateRange.js files.

Comment: I have updated the original post to reflect my progress.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you are using some method of automatically including bower installed scripts in your HTML. In the instance of the date-picker that you are installing it's failing to automatically wire-up this dependency.

I would suggest locating your **index.html** file or your default layout file. Once you've find this file you should hardcode a reference to the scripts mentioned above.

```
<script src="/public/lib/angular-datepicker/app/scripts/datePicker.js"></script>
<script src="/public/lib/angular-datepicker/app/scripts/dateRange.js"></script>
```

It's worth noting **Bower** is just a dependency management tool. It's a convenient way of installing third-party libraries. Once you've specified the dependency in your **bower.json** file (similarly with **package.json**) you simply need to run bower install in order to "fetch" those dependencies.

**Bower** will just download the dependencies via their registered repositories and place them within a directory in your application. In most applications you are required to include the dependencies yourself such as the method that I mentioned above (in the case of Javascript dependencies).

Your method of specifying the **Angular** dependencies looks correct so providing you add the markup above to your index.html or layout template everything should work correctly.

I hope this helps.